# How to properly handle const char* in c++

Tags: c++, char, constants

```
bool check(const char* pass);
```

1. Does const mean that I cannot modify char* inside the function?
2. Does char* c has any function like contains(char c) which checks if the char is inside char*?
3. How to get to 4th character in the char*?
4. Is there any function which gives the length of that char*. Beside checking where is '\0'?

Comment: Const protects his left side, unless there is nothing to his
left and only then it protects his right side

Comment: A `char*` does not "contain" characters. It does not have a string "inside" it, and it does not have a length. It points to a character, which may or may not be the first character of a nul-terminated string. The nul-terminated string contains characters and has a length.

Comment: Answer to 4 is a big fat **NO**. That is one of the many reasons you shold be using `std:string` not `char*`. You could carry on making life difficult for yourself or you could take the advice of experienced programmers. If you have some trouble using `std::string` then ask about how to use it properly, it will be worth it in the end.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Use `std::string` instead.**

1. No, it means you can't modify the `char`s.
2. `char*` is a pointer, it doesn't have any functions. You can look up `strchr`.
3. `pass[3]`
4. `strlen`, but it checks for `'\0'` internally.

Comment: Ad2. I am asking about any static or non static funtion which can check if char* type object contains certain character

Comment: "You can look up `strstr`, but it doesn't take a single char as parameter" -- or look up `strchr`, which does take a single character (it takes it as an `int` rather than a `char`).

Comment: @SteveJessop didn't know that existed.

Comment: @Luchian: we'll make C programmer of you yet  ;-) If you like `strchr` then `strrchr` will blow your mind (especially the first time you typo one for the other)